# Blacklist user id from using discord command discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Ok so i am making a bot for my friends server PBC and i wanted to blacklist a user with there
user id from using ONE COMMAND and they can use every other one so if you have anything that can help please help me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way of doing this with just an if statement

```
if ctx.author.id != [put the users id here]:
    await ctx.respond("You do not have permission to use this command")
    return
```

Place this at the very top of the command to block the user from using the command.

Answer (score 0):

just use `@commands.check()`
like this

```
def in_blacklist(ctx):
  return not str(ctx.message.author.id) in ['id1', 'id2'......]

@bot.command() #or @commands.command()
@commdnds.check(in_blacklist)
async def your_command(ctx):
  #do something....
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).